# Any recommendation to resize 3d image array which consists of only 0 and 1?

Tags: python, numpy, image-resizing, scipy.ndimage

I want to resize(downscale) the ground truth 3d images of brain tumor segmentation.

Here are some g.t. + brain images:

[image]

G.t. images are 3d numpy array and consist of only 0 and 1 value(only green voxel and black voxel, brain is not included in g.t. image).

```
def resize(img, shape, mode='nearest', orig_shape=None, order=3):
    """
    Wrapper for scipy.ndimage.zoom suited for MRI images.
    """

    if orig_shape == None: orig_shape = img.shape

    assert len(shape) == 3, "Can not have more than 3 dimensions"
    factors = (
        shape[0]/orig_shape[0],
        shape[1]/orig_shape[1], 
        shape[2]/orig_shape[2]
    )

    # Resize to the given shape
    return zoom(img, factors, mode=mode, order=order)

# original shape = (150, 512, 512)
# desired shape = (64, 192, 160)
```

I used scipy zoom, with order 3 and nearest mode. After resizing the images, some of them were ok but some weren't. You can see the problem in the 1st and 2nd images of the above. **There are many holes in tumor area which were not there before resizing.** The 3rd image doesn't seem to have the issue.

I tinkered some options in zoom function, but didn't find a proper solution. Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: instead of two unrelated images, we'd like to see the first one BEFORE and AFTER resizing. don't need the whole image, just crop the green part if too large.

Comment: what do you mean by _resizing_? It looks like from your images that the green mask has been resampled but not resized.

Comment: @DrBwts They were resized using zoom function of scipy package(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html). I think that i looks like that because matplotlib's figure size was fixed regradless of resizing..

Comment: add your code so we can see what parameters you used

Comment: @DrBwts I inserted the code. sorry.