# MRI mask 3D array resize with scipy.ndimage.zoom, the result is not binaray

Tags: python, scipy

I want to use 3D-UNet to do semantic segmentation to MRI data. I read the whole brain MRI data as a 3D array, the shape of it is (193,229,193). And I use scipy.ndimage.zoom() resize its mask to (256, 256, 128). Aftering resize, you can see the result:
Code:

```
resize_img = itpl.zoom(img, (resize[0] / img.shape[0], resize[1] / img.shape[1], resize[2] / img.shape[2]), mode='nearest')
```

[image]

The mask becomes to be not binary, 1 and 0.

What's the reason and how should I do to preprocessing the data in 3D-UNet.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was asked in another post [A weird image modification after applying scipy.ndimage.zoom function to a mri segmentation image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278256/a-weird-image-modification-after-applying-scipy-ndimage-zoom-function-to-a-mri-s/59279295#59279295?newreg=0d6e0a2d3c3c4664811c00f1eab59ff2) and addressed. You should add-in order=0 flag to your zoom call to keep the image binary. it'll fix the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).